# How to check version of gijgo/datepicker in the app?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

In my laravel 8 / Bootstrap 4 / jquery app I have problems with gijgo
datepicker ( https://github.com/atatanasov/gijgo/issues ) working not properly

and I want to check versions of all related libraries with :

```
alert( 'jQuery().jquery::'+jQuery().jquery )  // GOT 3.5.1
alert( "   bootstrap::"+jQuery.fn.tooltip.Constructor.VERSION ) // GOT 4.5.3
alert( "   bootstrap::"+jQuery.datepicker.Constructor.VERSION ) // GOT Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constructor' of undefined
```

I wonder if there is a way to check version of datepicker / If there is way to make script
to check all jQuery plugings installed in the app?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the source code even have any version property? Not all plugins do

Comment: In gijgo.min.js I did not find any version declared, neither version text  declaration found...

Comment: Ok, so that answers your question... it doesn't exist

Comment: Also If there is way to make script to check all jQuery plugings installed in the app?

Comment: You would need to compare all the default properties of `jQuery.fn` to what exists in your page but only after all the scripts have loaded. Inspect `$.fn` though and will see it has a lot of properties